# Are all "Theorems" necessarily in the "if - then" form?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, proof-theory

When someone talks about "**Theorems**" in Mathematics, something of the sort below comes to my mind.

> **Theorem 1**: For every two real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a \lt b$, there
>   exists a rational number $r$ satisfying $a \lt r \lt b$.

Basically, there's a **Hypothesis** (the "if" part) and a **Conclusion** (the "then" part). So if I were to, say, prove this theorem using contradiction, I would start by negating the conclusion and then proceeding logically until a contradiction is found with the hypothesis (*contrapositive proof*) or some other accepted fact. The hypothesis and conclusion can be seen very easily here. Let us take a different example.

> **Theorem 2**: There exists no rational number $r$ whose square is $2$.

I am having a hard time seeing what the hypothesis is in this case. Maybe if this theorem is worded in a different way, it might be obvious but that's just my opinion.

And if you're familiar with the proof of this theorem, the contradiction comes from the fact that we had supposed a rational number $\frac pq$ in lowest terms but after proceeding logically, we find a factor of $2$ common between $p$ and $q$ which goes against our assumption that we started with and so our proof ends.

**So my questions are**:

1. Are all "**Theorems**" necessarily in the "**if-then**" form?
2. What is the **Hypothesis** in **Theorem $2$**? Is the proof for this theorem a contrapositive proof?

I heartily welcome any extra information in relation to this question.

Comment: Theorem 2 may be written as "If $r$ is rational then $r^2\neq2$".

Comment: At a basic level, all theorems are proved assuming some axioms (usually ZFC), so all theorems can be expressed as "if <axioms> then <theorem>"

Comment: If $r^2=2$ then $r$ is not a rational number

Comment: @Arthur So the hypothesis is that $r$ is rational and the conclusion is $r^2 \neq 2$. And we started our proof assuming that $r^2 = 2$ and $r$ is rational. I am not sure that this counts as a proof by contradiction because we started by negating the conclusion as well as assuming that the hypothesis is true.

Comment: @Vasya This is the contrapositive of the above statement. I know they are equivalent but in relative terms, the hypothesis and conclusion are different for them.

Comment: There is a class of theorems called "theorem of the alternative", where exactly one statement is true. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma

Comment: @SalmanQureshi that's exactly what a proof by contradiction is.

Comment: @Arthur I think when we do proof by contradiction, we only assume the negation of the conclusion is true. We do not assume that the hypothesis stands true as well.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi No, that's a proof by contrapositive. You will never reach a contradiction that way, just the negation of the hypothesis.

Comment: @Arthur Isn't a contrapositive proof just a special class of proof by contradiction? Don't we always start a proof by contradiction by just negating the conclusion and if we reach a contradition of hypothesis, it becomes a contrapositive proof. And if we reach a contradiction with some other accepted fact, it's simply a proof by contradiction?

Comment: No, they are distinct (although very similar). Contrapositive is proving "if A then B" by showing "if not B then not A". Proof by contradiction is assuming not B, and possibly A, and then reaching an actual contradiction. Many proofs by contradiction are proofs by contrapositive with the addition of "assume A" at the start and "this contradicts A" at the end.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. Could you possibly cite me your source on this? Obviously, I can wait for you to dig up on this whenever you have time.

Comment: Every theorem T can be written as "if 0=0 then T". Not every theorem is *naturally* an implication, for example "the natural number 1 plus the natural number 1 equals the natural number 2" can be written as an implication but in the natural formulation it is just an equation. Similarly $(\forall x)(x=x)$ is already a formal statement and not an implication.

Comment: @Arthur Just a little off-topic but closely related, the method of direct proof only applies to Implications unlike indirect proof which can be applied to statements of any form?

Comment: Logic is implication which is If, Then, forming sequences. See Frege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we have to know what we mean with a theorem, for instance if we have a theorem such as

**Statement** *All numbers are equal to $0$*

**Theorem 1** *Statement is false*

We could of course rewrite the two sentences as a new theorem

**Theorem 2** *There exists a number that is not $0$*

But, what if wanted to represent Theorem 1 more generally (that is, without using anything said in the Statement), would we always be able to write a "Theorem 2".

Short answer, no.

**TL;DR** There are theorems that can't be written as "if, then".

If you want to read more about the topic, I'd suggest reading some First Order Logic (FOL), a subject where proofs and theorems get a new meaning.

**Edit**

Without giving any proofs, but as Salmon suggested, there are reasons as to why we can't reformulate everything, and it has to do with the axioms made in FOL, different sets of axioms yields different "types of logic", but i we restrict ourselfs to classical (what you're most likely used to) logic, we have "if-then" as an axiom, as well as falsum (that something is false) and the "for all"-statement. Not that it proves anything, but axioms are usually chosen such that they can't be derived from other axiom.

Comment: How about: "if by numbers we mean an element of (some nontrivial ring, for example), then statement is false", or "if we work in classical logic, then such and such is a theorem"

Comment: I sort of understand your point. Would you please elaborate a little on why all theorems can't be written as "if-then"? I don't have enough time on my hand right now to spare for a new subject.

Comment: Of course every theorem.can be rewritten as an if/then by butchering the phrasing, e.g. "if 0=0 the [insert theorem here]".  But this is not usually a natural way to express the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 2.

When I read a theorem, let's say "If A and B then C",  I find all its assumptions and conclusions and than I imagine they are written like this:

- Let A
- Let B
- Then C

If I wanted to prove it by contradiction, I would add an extra assumption,

- Let A
- Let B
- Let not C

and I would play with the statements until I find some contradicting.

Applying this to your **Theorem 2**, I would assume *nothing* - except axioms and to some point my knowledge -  and state

- Then $\neg \exists_{r\in \mathbb{Q}} \; r^2=2$

Now for the contradiction I would assume the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems of logic prove assertions of this type:

$$\Gamma \vdash a$$
which means that, starting from the assumptions in the set $\Gamma$, we can prove the statement $p$.  For example, $$a\to b, a\vdash b$$means that, given the assumptions “$a\to b$” (“$a$ implies $b$”) and “$a$” we can prove “$b$”.  Usually one can prove a meta-theorem called the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) that states that if $$\Gamma, a\vdash b$$ is provable, then so is $$\Gamma\vdash a\to b.$$

All these require the assumptions in the set $\Gamma$.  But $\Gamma$ may be empty, and if it is then $\Gamma\vdash p$ is an assertion of $p$ that requires no assumptions.  For example, in typical systems $$\vdash a\to(b\to a)$$ is provable, and one can understand this as a theorem with no if-then: “Whatever $a$ and $b$ are, it is provable that $a$ implies that $b$ implies $a$”.

You may object that this is just a rephrasing of “If $a$ is true then, if $b$ is true then $a$ is true”.  Very well. Most logics will also prove $$\vdash \lnot(a\land \lnot a),\tag1$$ which says that, whatever $a$ might mean, it is not the case that $a$ is both true and false. And many will prove $$\vdash a\lor \lnot a\tag 2$$ which says that any $a$ is either true or false.

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but I don't see anything in either $(1)$ or $(2)$ that resembles “if…then…”, so perhaps that will answer your question.